# Return more than one value in python function

Tags: python, return, tuples

I was trying to use *args with a for loop in python, however I don't see how to return all the values passed to the function, which should return all the even numbers

```
def f_even(*args):
    for item in args:
        if item%2 == 0:
            return item
```

The above code returns only the first value, as I guess after the return it goes out of the function. Indeed, if I use print instead, it works

I'm trying to find a way to return a tuple with all the even numbers when I pass let's say (1,2,3,4,5) to the function

Thank you!

Comment: So, return a tuple? `return x, y` is perfectly valid. Having a `return` inside a `for` loop, though, probably isn't what you wanted. `return` will immediately break you out of the function.

Comment: You should read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html and learn to use lists.

Comment: You can, for example, store the values to be returned in a list, then return the list. If you're feeling adventurous, it may be time to learn about generators!

Comment: Perhaps you should look into [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and the [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) statement?

Answer (score 1):

In python you can use list comprehension to do this. will make you code more readable and will shrink it too.

```
def f_even(*args):
   return [elem for elem in args if elem % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: This is through list comprehension I guess, very useful as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could slightly modify you function and make it a generator by using `yield`. This way your function wont end after returning first even number but will keep yielding them one by one.

```
def f_even(*args):
    for item in args:
          if item%2 == 0:
             yield item

for i in f_even(1,2,3,4,5):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
2
4
```

---

Or if you want to store all yielded values:

```
even_numbers = list(f_even(1,2,3,4,5))
print(even_numbers) # -> [2, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

Done, thank you all!!

`def f_even(*args):
    mylist = []
    for item in args:
          if item%2 == 0:
            mylist.append(item)
    return mylist`